# Как заставить прогресс бар не работать при запуске онлайн консультанта?

Tags: javascript, плагин

Как заставить прогресс бар Pace не работать при запуске онлайн консультанта?

Как заставить Pace не работать при запуске онлайн консультанта?
github.hubspot.com/pace

Проблема в том, что при запуске онлайн консультанта siteheart (когда оператор находится в онлайне), запускается индикатор загрузки и загрузка длиться 30-60 секунд. В настройках css стоит скрытие страницы во время работы индикатора загрузки. Получается, что посетитель хочет пообщаться, но срабатывает индикатор загрузки, и все содержимое скрывается.

пробовал прописывать опции, но не помогает.

```
<script>
paceOptions = {
 ajax: false, // disabled
 document: false, // disabled
 eventLag: false, // disabled
};
</script>
```

Помогите решить проблему
адрес сайта https://mirtechniki.net

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
<script>window.paceOptions = {ajax: false, document: false, eventLag: false};</script>
```